# Calling a chained function from a string in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, method-chaining

In node.js I am using a module that has deeply chained methods and I need to call different chains based on user input and there are too many permutations to do it with conditionals.

I would like to call something like this

```
var WP = require('wpapi');
var server = require('./server.js');
var string1 = 'pages;
var string2 = 'id';

// original call
server.wpEp.pages().id(parseInt(splitPath[2])).then(...);

// call I would like to make
server.wpEp.string1().string2(parseInt(splitPath[2])).then(...);
```

Thanks for your help

******* Edit...

Thanks for the input on the brackets.  That was very helpful and what I was looking for.  I was able to solve it be combining that with being able to break up the chains into single calls to better parse.  Here is what I ended up with:

```
chainRet = server.wpEp[string1]();
chainRet = chainRet[string2](parseInt(splitPath[2]));
chainRet.then(function (data){ rspD(data, rsp); }).catch(function (err){ rspE(req, err, rsp); });
```

Now I can parse through the input and selectively add each of the chained function calls based on the input string in a manageable fashion

Comment: Like this?
`server.wpEp[string1]()[string2](parseInt(splitPath[2])).then(...);`

Comment: You use the bracketed syntax to access a property by using the value of a variable.  There are many duplicates of this question.  I will see if I can find one and mark this a dup.